# I'm encountering an error I can't resolve

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse HTML and extract data from a website. However, when I try to access a specific element using `find()` or `select()` I receive the following error message:

> '[Error message]'

The element I'm trying to access does exist. I also imported the BeautifulSoup library correctly.

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL of the website you're scraping
url = "https://www.linkedin.com/"

# Send a GET request to the website
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Find the specific element you're interested in
    target_element = soup.find('div', class_='target-class')

    # Access the desired data within the element
    if target_element:
        data = target_element.text.strip()
        print("Data:", data)
    else:
        print("Element not found.")
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve the page. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

How to fix this error and successfully extract the desired data from the website?

Comment: you can't scrape linkedin with just requests. You may use selenium with/without packages like linkedin_scraper or scrape_linkedin but it still won't be easy.

Comment: have you ever print(soup) to check if the element does exist?